# Plug socket won't turn off even after replacing

Tags: electrical, wiring, socket

I had a problem with a plug socket where the socket wouldn't turn off so I replaced with another that I got from Screwfix and now a week later we have the same issue? The socket only gets used about twice a day max... The original socket was about 20 years old.

Seems odd/coincidental that 2 sockets have the same issue?

Regards
Liam

Comment: Is the socket controlled by a switch in the socket, or by a switch somewhere else?

Comment: Also what are you running off it. It seems unlikely but I wonder if it's overloaded so much something's melted.

Comment: Hi, it's a switch within the socket else that would have been the first thing I replaced and its only running a tv and surround sound system. Original socket had issue with just tv plugged into it. There wasn't any burn marks on old socket either. Very odd if this issue has just happened with 2 totally diffeeent sockets...

Comment: If you loosen the mounting screws a little bit, does the switch start working again? If they are done up too tight it can distort the socket and interfere with the operation of the switch.

Answer (score 1):

It must be a coincidence, I'd take the faulty socket back to Screwfix and get a replacement.

After removing the socket and disconnecting it from any wiring, you could test the switch with a continuity tester.

The only alternative explanations would be quite complicated. Even an overload is unlikely to produce the exact same symptoms in a new and a 20-year old socket. Anything that welds contacts together ought to trip a breaker, make a noise, a smell and leave visible evidence.

Comment: Hi this is my thought too, but didn't know if any other kind of weird issue could have been causing it as it's a bit of a lottery chance of it having happened on the same box for 2 different sockets.. I';ll just get a replacement like you say and hopefully it'll resolve :-)